# $.ajax check if return string is 'ERROR'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to check the value returned from $.ajax is a string 'ERROR', that I've echoed back from PHP.

```
if (this.data === "ERROR");
{ 
   return { 'bla' : 'bla' };
}
```

But it will trigger the `if` every time.. also with `==`

I tried:

```
   if (typeof(this.data) == 'string')
```

Seems to work, but still have the problem of returning an object when it's 'undefined', tried:

```
typeof(this.data) === 'string' || this.data=== 'undefined'
```

Tried all kinds of combinations, but simply said, what I want to do,
When there is not nicely formatted JSON, but only 'ERROR', then I want to give in my own default JSON object and continue, but for some reason the if statement will be true every time.

There must be a simpler way for this.

And I can't work with the `error:` or `succes:` 'classes' of $.ajax, because It's a custom error message I return.

Comment: You should show more code context show we might be able to see what this.data represents.

Comment: `if ( typeof this.data != 'undefined' && typeof this.data == 'string' )` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got an extra semicolon:

```
//                        ↓ here
if (this.data === "ERROR");
//                        ↑ here
```

Remove it.

Comment: LOL. Ah, JavaScript, you amuse me. A "normal" programming language would throw here.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas happens in other languages, too. I remember a couple of years ago I spent hours debugging this exact problem in Java. I've since cranked up my compiler warnings.

Comment: Java has an empty statement (`;`), too? `if (1) ;` doesn't throw in Java?

Comment: [`if(true);` is fine.](http://ideone.com/sa7AK) [`if(1);` won't compile](http://ideone.com/4KIKR) because Java doesn't perform type coercion.

Comment: I see, Java *does* have an empty statement.

Comment: Aw, jeez, thnx :P it was killing me.. at least you point it out and not make it seem like you copy pasted it...

Answer (score -1):

```
if (this.data === "ERROR") { 
   return { 'bla' : 'bla' };
}
```